How to get global variable from codeigniter4 filter which is declared in Controller?
Is it possible to get a variable value from CodeIgniter4 filter, which is declared in controller?
class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public $myVariable = 'value from controller';

    public function index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

I have individual code for each controller. I want to identify this from filter, which controller is executed and what is it's code.
